# SQL WHERE Clause for any value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm executing SQL against a MySQL database and trying to write commands to delete all rows in a table.  When I run "DELETE FROM MyTable" I get the error 1175 because a safety feature is turned on by default that forces you to specify a WHERE clause on the primary key.

I could turn this feature off, but I kind of like it, so I'm trying to modify my command to have the same effect by adding the WHERE clause.  So, this works:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyID > 0
```

In deleting all rows greater where MyID is greater than zero, but I'm looking for a truly universal one that would work for any MyID values.  I tried these

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyID = ANY

DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyID = *
```

But they are syntax errors.  The doc on the WHERE clause says it just accepts =,<,>,>=,<=,<>,BETWEEN,LIKE,and IN, but nothing that looks like it accepts anything.

Is there a proper syntax for the WHERE conditional that accepts any value?

thank you.

Comment: `Where MyId = MyId` ?

Comment: @Stu, `or MyID is NULL`

Comment: Or, `Where 1=1`

Comment: or  simply `where 1=1`

Comment: `MyId` can't be NULL if it's a primary key

Comment: @jarlh - Why would it be always true?

Comment: Why not truncate?

Comment: @stu, correct. (Seems like I didn't read the question carefully enough...) Then `1 = 1` doesn't work either.

Comment: It seems to not like MyID = MyID, still trips the 1175 error

Comment: @PM77-1, add it to `Where MyId = MyId`. (I wasn't aware of that MyID is not null.)

Comment: *I'm looking for a truly universal one that would work for any MyID values* so how does `> 0` *not* work for any values, can values be negative?

Comment: @stu, no, but I assume they could be `fred`, `bill`, ..... just wondering out loud here

Comment: @Stu, I'm writing sort-of middleware, so yeah the user of my code could decide to use negative values for the primary key

Comment: @Chris assuming a PK is always an integer/numeric type then `>= -2147483647` would work as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
 TRUNCATE MyTable;
```

then you don't need any condition, as you should have DELETE privileges

> TRUNCATE TABLE empties a table. It requires the DROP privilege. Logically, TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to a DELETE statement that deletes all the rows, or a sequence of DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements.

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

The error is related to the `sql_safe_updates` client option (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates).

One way to circumvent the safe updates mode is to use a `LIMIT` clause on your query. You can use any value, even a value that is far larger than the number of rows in your table.

```
DELETE FROM MyTable LIMIT 9223372036854775807;
```

You can also disable the safe updates mode, then run the DELETE normally:

```
SET sql_safe_updates=0;
DELETE FROM MyTable; -- returns no error
```

TRUNCATE TABLE is a better solution, if you want to delete all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a compound condition.

```
WHERE id IS NULL OR id IS NOT NULL;
```

Then again, maybe the safety condition is there for an important reason that you should not get around.

Comment: Since `MyID` is a Primary Key - `NOT NULL` would be enough.

Comment: Strangely, MyID = 100 works, but MyID IS NOT NULL still trips 1175

Comment: IS NULL does not trip 1175, but IS NOT NULL trips 1175.  Pretty annoying, since I am making the intent explicit.