# MySQL update fails with 'You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.'

Tags: mysql, security, sql-update

I have been getting this error message from MySQL

> ERROR 1175 (HY000): You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.

The query I use is this:

```sql
update custcopy set cust_contact=null where cust_id='1000000005';
```

The information about the MySQL I use is "Ver 8.0.32 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)". And the scheme of the table I accessed is as follows:

```
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cust_id      | char(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_name    | char(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_address | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_city    | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_state   | char(5)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_zip     | char(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_country | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_contact | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cust_email   | char(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I consulted the mysql documentation and found that [this statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates:%7E:text=It%20is%20possible%20for%20UPDATE%20and%20DELETE%20statements%20to%20produce%20an%20error%20in%20safe%2Dupdates%20mode%20even%20with%20a%20key%20specified%20in%20the%20WHERE%20clause%2C%20if%20the%20optimizer%20decides%20not%20to%20use%20the%20index%20on%20the%20key%20column%3A) may be helpful, but I don't quite understand why.

I need a query that would not cause that error, and disabling the SQL_SAFE_UPDATES is not an option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: You can also temporarily work around the safe-updates restriction by using LIMIT on your UPDATE statement. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186791/sql-where-clause-for-any-value/75187391#75187391 The example in that question is for DELETE, but the same works for UPDATE.

Comment: I also notice that your DESCRIBE output shows that _none_ of the columns are key columns. You should consider defining a key for your table. If your key were `cust_id`, then the safe-updates requirement would be satisfied without having to work around it.

Comment: Logically, `cust_id` should be the primary key of the table. Not only will this silence the warning, but also make the query much more efficient.